# Best way to determine that a UIViewController has been loaded, and has a valid view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

When the view property of a UIViewController is accessed, it first checks to see if it's got an existing view, and returns that. If not, it loads its nib or calls -loadView.

When a controller receives a -didReceiveMemoryWarning message, the default behavior is to remove that cached view (assuming it's not in use at the time).

If I override -didReceiveMemoryWarning, how can I determine whether the view has been cleared? My understanding is that the default implementation checks to see if self.view.superview == nil. If so, it clears the cached view. Of course, it first checks to see if there *is* a cached view, and if not, it does nothing. However, I, as a subclass, can't call self.view.superview, for if there *isn't* a view, it'll generate one.

So, how do I figure out if _view exists? (I can't just look at _view; I get linking errors when building for the device).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in your situation it's best to do something like:

```
- (void)setView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (!view)
    {
         // Clean up code here
    }

    [super setView:view];
}
```

Comment: This seems somewhat fragile (it relies on Apple always using their own accessors), but does seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: I agree that it's slightly fragile, but there is nothing else documented, and is certainly less fragile than accessing ivars directly

Comment: [`- [UIViewController isViewLoaded]`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1076425/242933).

Answer (score 67):

Since iPhone OS 3.0, you can use the [`isViewLoaded`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isViewLoaded) method to see if a view is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [object_getIvar()](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001418-CH1g-SW1) to get at the value without going through the accessor. In essence, it lets you get at _view without needing to link against it. On the other hand, it has the potential to break if the actual ivar goes away or is renamed. Traditionally that was never a real concern, but the iPhone uses the modern runtime which does not suffer from fragile base class issues, so Apple might feel more inclined to make those sorts of changes.